# opennlp sample training data for disease

Tags: nlp, semantic-web, semantics, opennlp

I'm using OpenNLP for data classification. I could not find TokenNameFinderModel for disease [here](http://opennlp.sourceforge.net/models-1.5/). I know I can create my own model but I was wondering is there any large sample training data available for disease?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a good NER training model in OpenNLP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011615/how-to-create-a-good-ner-training-model-in-opennlp)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily create your own training data-set using the [modelbuilder addon](https://github.com/apache/opennlp-addons/tree/master/modelbuilder-addon) and follow some rules as mentioned here to train create a  good [NER model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32011615/how-to-create-a-good-ner-training-model-in-opennlp?rq=1).

you can find some help using modelbuilder addon [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21617540/how-to-update-an-existing-named-entity-recognition-model-rather-than-creatin).

It is basically, you put all the information in a text file and the NER entities in another. The addon searches for a paticular entity and replace it with the required tag. Hence producing the tagged data. It must be pretty easy to use this tool!

Hope this helps!